# how to make an action with a thread using a timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have these code lines in C#,

```
hilos = new Thread[Count];

hilos[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(EventoPeriodico));
hilos[i].Start();
```

so I want to call the function "EventoPeriodico" repeatedly every certain time to save some information, but I also have another functions that I would like to call inside differents threads, and each thread has its own different time. Every function can be call with distincts threads and timers.

The user will select some tags and from that point he will assign a condition and time to decide when the information is going to be saved (that's what we call event or action). For example: The user selects a "periodic event" which saves a tag constantly (for example, the tag1 is saving every two minutes). The user selects a "when the condition specified is true" (The tag2 value will be saved only when its value is less than 30). But the user can select again a periodic event with other tag and time. The events must be running at the same time.

Comment: Sounds like you want a DispatcherTimer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You don't create a thread to execute a periodic task. Rather, you create a timer and tell it what method to execute, and when. There are many different timers in .NET. Which one you use depends on your application. You might want a `DispatcherTimer`, a Windows Forms Timer, a `System.Threading.Timer`, or a `System.Timers.Timer`. What type of application are you creating? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx for a good overview.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having one timer for each user action. Obviously you'll need to come up with a way to parameterize what happens with each action. Without knowing more about your application, I can't suggest how it would be done. What kind of actions will the user want to specify?

Comment: The user will select some tags and from that point he will assign a condition and time to decide when the information is going to be saved (that's what we call event or action). For example:

The user selects a periodic event which saves a tag constantly (for example, the tag1 is saving every two minutes). 
The user selects a when the condition specified is true (The tag2 value will be saved only when its value is less than 30).
But the user can select again a periodic event with other tag and time.

The events must be running at the same time.

Comment: This usually requires an insight: just *one* timer is enough to time any number of timed events.  All you have to time is the next one(s) that is due.  Also the way the .NET System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer classes work.